Google voice typing/search. it's almost unusable
I've been trying to use Google Voice typing and it is often a nightmare.
Slight pauses = end of voice typing recording/searching on incomplete queries.
Google voice typing API gives the '??*!'??! ' presented in the following image.
Please tell how to what's going on here and how to fix it please. In layman's terms 

List item


It's hard to understand your question. If this is a question about the API, it's off topic. Also, there is no image included.

Please [edit] your question so we better understand the problem. Let us know the web application you are using if applicable. If the question isn't improved it is liable to be closed for lacking detail.
